# Hide a div inside a modal if result is true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to hide a div in a BS modal when a result is true or false. 
This should be very straight forward but I can't get it to work. I have one Bootstrap Modal which is filled with JSON content from a button click.

Modal HTML:

```
<div data-show="false" data-width="800" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="modal fade in" id="shop-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        ... content ... 
        <div class="wqs-form"> 

        </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Script:

```
function quick_shop(url, vid){
  $('.products-loader').show();

    $.getJSON(url, function (data){
      $('#shop-modal').modal('show');
      .... etc etc

      if(product.stock.available == false){
        $('#shop-modal').closest('.wqs-form').hide();
      }
      ..... 
      ....
```

I think the script doesn't know which modal it is in. So what I already tried is adding an extra class to the modal like so

```
$('#shop-modal').modal('show').addClass('product'+vid+'');
```

That doesn't work neither the div just won't hide or remove or whatever I try to do with it.

I also tried things like `parent()`. `find()` etc but with no luck.

Anyone?

Comment: Could you console.log (..) the element you have in the script and use the HTML/DOM inspector to ensure its the right element? You could also use the DOM inspector to find your way to the child element if it's contained in there.

Comment: Also before you check that you wanna check if your if-statement is even executing! Could be a condition fail

Comment: I concur with the above, this line `if(product.stock.available == false){` doesn't look like it should work in your example, as 'product' hsa not been defined. Does it maybe need to be `data.product...`. Put a `console.log(data)` under your `$.getJSON` to see what comes back. In most good browser consoles you should be able to dig your way down the tree to find what you are after.

Comment: @RobQuincey: The script itself works. It is indeed defined as `product = data.product`.

Comment: @Ozzy: Can you take a look [link](http://loveandluck.webshopapp.com/en/). Click `add` on both products. The "add to cart" button inside the modal should disappear when product is out of stock. Complete code is found in main.js on row 62.

Comment: @Ozzy: The if-statement is executing. It returns true or false when needed. How do I use the dom-inspector to find the child element?

Comment: I use Firefox with FireBug plugin, all the browsers are slightly different but in the menu you should find Web Developer Tools so you click that or press F12 (shortcut) and then click on the element from the console log and it should take you to the DOM tab to inspect it.

Comment: Re: the link: I'm away from my computer at the moment,  on my mobile when I get a break. I don't have developer tools on mobile.